# Twitter card automatically generated from og:image

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph, meta, twitter-card

I've seen websites that, by looking in their source, don't have any `twitter:*` meta tags like:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" /> 
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5510/14338202952_93595258ff_z.jpg" />
```

but that still appear with a Twitter card when sharing the URL on Twitter.

They had `og:image` meta tags, so I thought that **a page that has Opengraph tags: `og:image`, `og:title`, etc. would automatically be rendered with a card on Twitter**. But after testing, it seems that no.

Question: is there a Twitter feature that makes that a page with no Twitter-specific meta tags, but Opengraph tags will be rendered automatically with a summary or summary_large_image card?

Comment: If a page has OpenGraph tags only, a summary card may be rendered if an og:type is present (per https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/markup)

Comment: Thanks @AndyPiper. Yes I see `then a summary card may be rendered`, so there is no real defined rule?

Comment: The rule is that a summary card will be displayed if it can be generated from the minimal three OpenGraph tags.